# Drawing ellipse in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, ellipse

How to draw ellipse in OpenLayers? I have not problems with drawing circles, or MultiPolygons, but i need to draw simple ellipse and not found any functions for this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this extension example -->

http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.drawregular.html

Use a number less than three and you will be able to draw an ellipses.

Here is the api -->http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.interaction.DrawRegular.html

Comment: For a solution without third party libraries you can use a geometry function with the draw interaction as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html  Working snippet of that example extended to include ellipses here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647238/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-using-openlayers3

Answer (score 1):

I should use the code like this:

```
 var ellipseInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'LineString',
  source: vectorLayer.getSource(),
  maxPoints: 3,
  geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
  var center = coordinates[0];
  var first = coordinates[1];
  var dx = center[0] - first[0];
  var dy = center[1] - first[1];
  var radius1 = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if (coordinates.length > 2) {
    var last = coordinates[2];
    dx = center[0] - last[0];
    dy = center[1] - last[1];
  }
  var radius2 = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius1);
  var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circle, 64);
  polygon.scale(radius2 / radius1, 1);
  polygon.rotate(rotation, center);
  if (!geometry) {
    geometry = polygon;
  } else {
    geometry.setCoordinates(polygon.getCoordinates());
  }
  return geometry;
 }
});
```

which has been modified slightly from this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-shapes-fr7dz?file=/index.js:111-163

by changing the `fromCircle` conditions

[Moving geom.Polygon.circular in OpenLayers 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162781/moving-geom-polygon-circular-in-openlayers-3)